# Treat first page like the rest

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

I am new to LaTeX, and I am having trouble with the first page since the first page is being treated differently from the rest. First custom headers and footers wouldn't apply to the first page, but I eventually fixed that. Now I have the following spacing issue:
[image: This isn't spaced correctly]

I would like to have the same space before "Problem 1" that "Problem 2" has. In my example, the first page isn't a special page such as a ToC or anything. Being that I have already had issues with the first page, is there any way to signal to the compiler that the first page should get absolutely no special treatment so I do not have to worry about this issue again for something else? (Or perhaps creating a blank first page and then removing it from the final pdf file if that is possible)

Here is the code for the document if it helps:

```
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\stepcounter{Problem}
\section*{Problem \theProblem}
\*Removed*\

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\stepcounter{Problem}
\section*{Problem \theProblem}
...
```

I attempted to fix the problem by adding `\null` before `\section*{Problem 1}`, but this gave too much space, and I feel it would be unnatural and harder to maintain if I set the top margin by exact pixel values to line it up correctly.

Below I attached my formatting for the header.

```
\title{USAMTS Round 1}
\author{Nicholas Pipitone}
\date{September 2015}

\newcounter{Problem}
\newcounter{Pages}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{USA Mathematical Talent Search}
\rhead{Year: 27\\Round: 1\\Problem: \theProblem}
\lhead{Student: Nicholas Pipitone\\Username: npip99\\ID\#: 99999}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \thePages}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
```

Comment: The problem probably is in your document preamble which you not provide. With simple `article` and definition of new counter `problem` your code works as expected.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're probably using `fancyhdr` and getting a warning in the log file that the `\headheight` is too small, together with a suggested value. Are you also loading `geometry`?